# check if value is a string or a number in mocha/chai test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm curious about how to test a `value` to be a `string` **or** `number` with `chai`. I know how to write a test for a `string` or a `number`, when it's a strict test. But how to deal with it, when `value` could either be one of them?

**A test for a string:**

```
describe("test", () => {
    it("should be a string", () => {
       let value = "1234";
       value.should.be.a("string");
    });
});
```

**A test for a number:**

```
describe("test", () => {
    it("should be a number", () => {
       let value = 1234;
       value.should.be.a("number");
    });
});
```

Is there a build-in way of `chai` to do this?

I know that I could do some workarounds, like below. But that feels kind of *hacky*.

```
describe("test", () => {
    it("should be a number or string", () => {
       let value = 1234;
       (typeof value).should.be.oneOf(["string", "number"]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own method:

```
chai.Assertion.addMethod('stringOrNumber', function () {
    //Check if it is a string or a number here
});
```

Then in your test:

```
expect(myValue).to.be.stringOrNumber();
```

See [plugin utilities documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/plugins/#addProperty-section)

Comment: This is pretty cool...I havent dug deep enough into chai, so I didnt realize i could add my own assertions. Will definitely be using this in the future.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you! But I would think there is such option already build-in I don't know yet. And for just one check it seems to be a overhead to implement an own method. But for other things that is a useful idea it's really neat to know! Thanks!